# Need help beginning a modular congruence proof

Tags: proof, modular-arithmetic

(∀a, b ∈ Z) a<sup>2</sup> + b<sup>2</sup> − 3 ≡|≡ 0 mod 4.
Hi, I'm not too sure where to start with this proof and just need some pointers on how to approach this.

Comment: Subtracting 3 doesn't matter modulo 3, and this formula is weird in general. Is this really it? If it was `mod 4`, then it would make sense.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: you can ask this question in https://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

a=b=3 gives 9+9-3 = 15 which is congruent to 0 mod 3, disproving your statement.

Comment: My bad it was suppose to be mod 4, sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Then just have a look on whether a, b are even or odd.